# how to rotate scaled-vector (orientation) by scaled-vector (rotation)

Tags: angular-momentum, vectors, rotation, rotational-kinematics, linear-algebra

Recently I seem to have gotten the physics-engine portion of my 3D simulation/game engine [apparently] working correctly.  The most convenient way to store and compute position and orientation are in 3-element vectors (though my code actually holds both in the x,y,z elements of a 4-element vector).

The orientation is kept in what seems to be commonly called "scaled-vector" form, where the axis is defined by the vector direction, and the rotation angle is the length of the vector (in radians).

After streamlining the code for a long time, the code is quite short and sweet (simple)... except where the code computes the new orientation (where torque forces and previous angular velocity applied to the previous orientation generate a new angular velocity and orientation).  Whether this computation is done with matrices or quaternions, this section of code is relatively messy, extensive and slower to execute.

I'm not good at math (barely good enough to get the physics working after reading about ten million articles and books).  But I have a very strong intuitive feeling there must be a way to rotate an orientation in scaled-vector form by a rotation also in scaled-vector form.  This seems "obvious" to math-moron-me because a quaternion is equivalent to a scaled-vector, and because a quaternion is equivalent to a 4-element axis-angle vector which is itself equivalent to a scaled-vector.

Furthermore, I have found that all other computations in the physics engine with scaled-vectors are [somewhat to much] simpler and faster than any alternative, which makes me think there is something inherently good about these scaled-vectors.  For one thing they don't get messed up when objects get rotating very fast (more than pi or 2pi per physics interval), while other approaches do.

Perhaps I've given more background than I should, but I do so to justify my desire to find the math to "rotate an orientation" AKA "rotate a rotation" with in scaled-vector form without converting them to quaternions or rotation matrices and back again, which is what I do now.

I've searched far and wide, but can't find the equations.  I've found about ten million versions with quaternions and rotation matrices, but that's not what I'm looking for.  Is my weakness in math hiding some obscure reason that this operation inherently can't be formulated with scaled-vectors?

Or can some math genius out there somewhere just whip these equations out, and receive my sincere admiration and appreciation?

PS:  If someone provides these equations, I have a feeling many physics-engine and game-engine developers will find them as extremely helpful as me.

Comment: Did you get your math from a standard textbook on computer graphics or game design? If you did and the book is any good, it will have given you pretty much the best general purpose ways of doing these operations, already. The people who write the textbooks on those things are usually quite competent in these matters.  Unless you have a special case of rotation (certain angles or combinations of angles) it's unlikely that you can do considerably better than what the standard solutions suggest. The other question is whether this is really the limiting aspect of the game engine.

Comment: @CuriousOne: As I said, I've read a huge number of articles about this specific topic (via google search), plus several books I purchased.  You'd be surprised how many different ways different people accomplish these things.  I've done my best to understand the material, and to create my own way of implementing routines (which has ended up very much more compact, efficient and non-problematic).  I gave one example of that.  Another was transforming to local-coordinates so I could compute more efficiently with the native (local-coords) inertia tensor (extremely uncommon, but "better").

Comment: I wasn't trying to question your research. I know that this has many different and specialized solutions, I am just not sure there is a magic one that uses an order of magnitude fewer operations. I did try to find something similar for a computer arithmetic problem, once, but only one algorithm yields large gains. For long vectors one can use an FFT to bring some problems down from $O(n^2)$ to $O(n\log n)$. I don't know if it's applicable to the rotation of large numbers of vectors.

Comment: I don't expect (or need) anywhere near an order-of-magnitude gain!  You might be surprised how much time and effort I spend to find 10% to 50% gains... when the code is executed many times per frame.  In this case, every object in the simulation that has a force applied executes this part of the code.  Since in many simulations every object is tweaked by "gravitational forces" and often other forces, this code might execute for thousands of objects at the frame rate (30 to 60 per second).  So, it can add up.  Frankly, part of my irritation is because scaled-vectors work so great elsewhere.

Comment: Re *I've found about ten million versions with quaternions and rotation matrices, but that's not what I'm looking for.* Why not? That's the way to go. Quoting from the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions, "Combining two successive rotations, each represented by an Euler axis and angle, is not straightforward ... It is best to employ the rotation matrix or quaternion notation, calculate the product, and then convert back to Euler axis and angle."

Comment: ***I so wish someone would just answer my question!***

Comment: To me, it is unlikely that an answer to your question exists that isn't just converting to quaternions or rotation matrices in disguise. That said, I'm unfamiliar with scaled-vector representations (googling just leads back to this page). Could you explain a bit more about it? For example, say your object is a line from {0, 0, 0} to the point {0, 0, 1} w.r.t. object coordinates. How would you take a scaled vector and use it to determine the new endpoint of the line?

Comment: A "scaled-vector" is just a vector that is not required to be a unit-vector.  In other words, a "scaled-vector" is a regular old normal (but not normalized) vector.  An "orientation" or "rotation" can be specified with a vector in two ways (that I am aware of), or a quaternion or a 3x3 "rotation matrix".  One of the vector representations is called "axis-angle", which is the rotation-axis in a unit-vector in the x,y,z components, plus the angle in radians in the w component.  The "scaled-vector" is the same except multiply the angle times the x,y,z elements to produce that 3-element vector.

Comment: More: a "scaled-vector" can be converted to and from:  an "axis-angle" vector, a quaternion, and a 3x3 "rotation matrix".  To me, this makes it self-evident that an equivalent computation exists for orientations and rotations in the "scaled-vector" form.  Also, to answer me with "just convert back and forth to matrix" is equivalent to telling people "do not seek to rotate with quaternion math operations because you can convert quaternions to matrices, perform matrix math, then convert back to quaternions".  Clearly it was and is worthwhile to find quaternions formulations, hence my question.

Comment: The best answers you can get on this site are the usual textbook answers, as far as I can tell. That's as it should be, this is not the forum for personal theories and inventions. I still think that you should look at global optimizations. There is only so much one can cut out on the single operation level, but global optimizations (e.g. by pre-sorting vectors into classes and transforming the entire class at the same time) may get you orders of magnitude speedups if you are dealing with thousands or millions of objects.

Comment: @CuriousOne:  You can be certain that I do all those things too, and multi-thread, and anything else I can think up.  Probably this question belongs in "mathematics" because probably math people are used to manipulating symbols to reformulate expressions.  Oh, and I wrote quite a few key routines in hand-optimized 64-bit SIMD/AVX assembly language!  I posted this question because compared to all the other computations to transform forces into linear and angular accelerations, velocities, positions/orientations, this little section is gross, and quite clearly shouldn't be (see reasons above).

Comment: What you are asking doesn't belong in mathematics, either, but in computer graphics. Physics deals with the physical world, not with its efficient computation and mathematics deals with the structure of objects that satisfy certain formal criteria, whether those objects exist or not. At this point you seem to be upset about us not appreciating what "else" you are doing, even though none of this is even a physics question, to begin with. I gave you my best shot at the answer, already. That's all I can do. Good luck!

Comment: You didn't answer my question, which would at least have helped me understand why you are certain that the method you want must exist: how do you actually employ "scaled vectors" to rotate ordinary vectors? The reason I doubt that there is a method for rotating scaled vectors by other scaled vectors is that rotations AREN'T vectors - they do not satisfy the basic requirements of vector algebra. That, and the study of rotations is quite old now.

Comment: @user27118: I convert the scaled-vectors to rotation-matrices or to quaternions, then perform the rotation, then convert the results back to scaled-vectors.  You are technically correct that an "axis-angle" vector is not a "true vector" (at least I suspect that's true, because the "angle" part seems sorta non-commensurate with the axis).  HOWEVER, a quaternion isn't exactly a vector either, but you can convert vectors to quaternions and quaternions to vectors all you wish (and people do that all the time).  And people "rotate" with quaternions, even though the above is true.

Comment: @user27118:  Further, it may be true that the 3-element "scaled-vectors" that I'm talking about aren't technically "true vectors" in a strict sense, since the magnitude of the vector is interpreted to be "the rotation angle in radians".  I'm not a math-guy, but that makes me think that none of these are actually "true vectors" as much as they look like vectors (due to the way they are interpreted).  But *clearly* a 3-element "scaled-vector" or a 4-element "axis-angle vector" or a "4-element quaternion" *can* designate "orientation" and *can* designate "rotation".

Comment: But the reason quaternion logic can be used for rotations is precisely that they aren't vectors and don't use vector logic. For example, rotations don't commute, and neither does quaternion multiplication. Although you only need three elements to specify a rotation (such as Euler angles), those three elements aren't elements of a vector. Consider: if you change a "scaled vector" amplitude by 2$\pi$, you get the same object back, explicitly violating the requirements for a vector space. You should think of this as a compressed format.

Comment: Just as you need to convert a JPEG to a bitmap to perform many image manipulations, you would have to convert scaled vectors to a different representation to perform rotations. Fortunately, quaternions don't take up much additional memory, and have all the other advantages you mention in your question.